# What happens to my call stack when I restart my node.js web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing some asynchronous code using the co package, that is triggered when a user does an action but does not return anything to that user. I need to know if these actions will be lost if during execution the node.js server using Express.js is restarted.

Comment: If you restart, the environment is re-created anew, so you'll loose everything that was in-memory before that. Unless you have something that persists the in-memory stuff somehow and restores it.

Comment: How can I maintain the call stack between restarts? 
We have deployments every now and then and we do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

When a transaction is ordered, it prints the transaction details that were exported using redis in json format, and you are delete that data when the transaction is complete.

And before you started the new process, you checked the unfinished process,

if there are unfinished transactions, process them first.
Note that you keep unfinished transaction details in a serialized manner in redis.

Also have should look : Queue systems